# Rendering fullcalendar to pdf using wkhtmltopdf allways omit Days

Tags: c#, fullcalendar, wkhtmltopdf

I'm currenty using Wkhtmltopdf to export Full Calendar to PDF.
My Html code is (only Body) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fine &amp; Country</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fenix:400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost:21792/Content/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://localhost:21792/Content/fullcalendar_year.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://localhost:21792/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://localhost:21792/Content/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>

        .fc-left, .fc-right
        {
            display: none;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar-full"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/fullcalendar_year.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/Custom/pt.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:21792/Scripts/Custom/HollidayPdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        while (window.status != "READY");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I guarantee that json calls finish before load the page.
My Javascript code is (File: HollidayPdf.js):

```js
var fullCalendarApproval;
var events, notWorkingDays;
var date = new Date();

var isLoadedNotWorkingDays = false, isLoadedEvents = false;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:21792/Hollidays/LoadNotWorkingDays',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        isLoadedNotWorkingDays = true;
        notWorkingDays = data;
    }
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:21792/Hollidays/ListAllHolidaysSchedulled',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        isLoadedEvents = true;
        events = data;

    }
});


while (!isLoadedNotWorkingDays && !isLoadedEvents);

var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();


if (jQuery('#calendar-full').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#calendar-full').fullCalendar({

        defaultView: 'year',

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'year,month'
        },
        yearColumns: 2,
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: false,
        events: events,
        loading: function (bool) {
        },
        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            jQuery.each(notWorkingDays, function (i) {
                jQuery('.fc-day[data-date="' + notWorkingDays[i]["date"] + '"]').css('background', "#e2dec1");
            });
        }

    });

}

window.status = "READY";
```

But every time i execute wkhtmltopdf with the following line i get only Weeks.
My command line is : 
**wkhtmltopdf.exe --window-status READY D:\Projects\CRM\FineCountry.html D:\Projects\CRM\test1.pdf**

For what i've seen only transform part of the calendar, it's weird.

Does anyone faced similar Issue???